# App Engine memcache async operation get_multi_async

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Ho to use memcache get_multi_async.

Doc says it returns "dictionary" of values.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass.html#Client_get_multi_async

I was expecting it to return some kind of "async object" on which i can do get_result() later.

Am i missing something ??

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to pass in [an RPC object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html); the dictionary it speaks of will be obtained via the `get_result()` function on the RPC object.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `get_multi_async` actually returns an `RPC` object which you use to later do the result.

```
client = memcache.Client()
rpc = client.get_multi_async(['key1', 'key2'])
# Do other work
result = rpc.get_result()
```

If you want, you can [make your own `RPC` object](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions#Client_create_rpc) which allows you to control the deadline and also provide a callback to be invoked when the fetch is finished:

```
client = memcache.Client()
rpc = memcache.create_rpc(deadline=30, callback=my_callback)
client.get_multi_async(['key1', 'key2'], rpc=rpc)
```

Note that the RPC object you make has to be from the `memcache` package, not the `urlfetch` one.